# Select input type in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have to use multiple selectboxes in one component. But i have to make them control component when i set the value property as state it is not working properly. When i use one selectbox the other also changes. How can i solve this problem.
Thanks.

```
`
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
};

const [value, setValue] = useState();
`

.....................

`
{item.extraItem ? item.extraItem.map((byProduct) => (
       <div>
          <p className="price-text">{byProduct.extraPrice}$</p>
          <p>{byProduct.extraName}</p>
          <select name={byProduct.extraName} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
       </div>
)): null}
`
```

Comment: @DBS yes they are using the same value state, how can i you prove that. Do i have to use useReducer ?

Comment: It's better to define the state holding the value of the select boxes as an array as you have more than one of those. And in the handle change use the index to set the value of that particular selectbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**when i set the value property as state it is not working properly. When i use one selectbox the other also changes**

its because for all selectboxes you are using common value from state,to over come this you should use individual state values for each selectbox
for example you state should be like

```
 const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
```

now you event handler should be like

```
 const handleChange = (index,value) => {
      let curValues=[...values];
      curValues[index]=value;
    setValue(curValues);
};
```

and your render method should be like

```
  {item.extraItem ? item.extraItem.map((byProduct,index) => (
   <div>
      <p className="price-text">{byProduct.extraPrice}$</p>
      <p>{byProduct.extraName}</p>
      <select name={byProduct.extraName} value={values[index]} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(index,e.target.value)}>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
   </div>
 )): null}
```